# how i can use json in react native with axios

Tags: arrays, json, react-native

[image: wmJ1Q]
I use React Native for WordPress now I can get information in post table,
so
how we can separate the field content information includes text, img and the other information... by the JSON and show them in tags?

Comment: You have to write your own parser, `p` and `img` tags don't exist in React Native. Your function would have to transform `p` tags to `Text` and `img` to `Image`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can not write this code because I do not have enough experience to guide me further.